# how to create a documentation help from xml files

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2019, documentation

First, this question is not duplicated, there are some related questions but they are very old and not what I need.

How can create GUI documentation help like "Microsoft Compiled HTML Help" for example using XML files (generated from VS2019)?

Here is how my XML files look like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>my.project.name</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="M:test.generating.documentation">
            <summary>
            test generating documentation 
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:test.generating.documentation">
            <summary>
            test1
            test2
            </summary>
        </member>
    </members>
</doc>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools available. One of them is [VSdocman](https://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) (I am the author).